# Generating OCR for pdf page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, pdf-generation, ocr, apex-code, visualforce

We have render as pdf in salesforce , but my requirement is generating OCR markings in that pdf page so that it can be used for processing in OCR system
Could any body please help me on this?

Comment: do you use getContentAsPDF? maybe add needed markings to page itself?

Comment: Yes we can add those markings in page , is there a way to add those markings in exact co-ordinates?

Comment: Cannot say for sure, try `<apex:component>` with `<div style="position: absolute;">` inside, or just `<apex:outputPanel with style="position:absolute;">` - maybe it will work